# parameter 'int1' is missing a type annotation in callback 'custdice' in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm updating my bot to have slash commands and I encountered an issue, whenever there are parameters given in the command it refuses to even start the bot even though the parameters themselves are referenced in the command, the command in question is this one

```
@bot.tree.command()
async def custdice(ctx, int1, int2):
    msg = await ctx.send("You have rolled a dice! Rolling in progress... :game_die:")
    number1 = int(int1)
    number2 = int(int2)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    await msg.edit(content=f"You have rolled a dice! Rolling in progress... :game_die: \n\nThe number you rolled is {randint(number1, number2)}!")
```

if this is something easy to fix please go easy on me, I'm very new to coding in general so I have no clue what could be causing this issue.

Comment: You should use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application commands, the type of the parameters has to be known because Discord treats them differently (eg. showing a list of members, roles, channels, checking for valid numbers, etc).

You haven't provided a type annotation for any of them, and the error is telling you to do so. It quite literally says what's causing the issue:

> parameter 'int1' is missing a type annotation

Going off of the names, I'm going to assume these are `int`s.

```py
async def custdice(ctx, int1: int, int2: int):
#                           ^^^^^      ^^^^^
    ...
```

**Also** application commands take an `Interaction` instead of `Context`, so naming your first argument `ctx` instead of something like `interaction` is very confusing & misleading. You should rename it. `Context` & `Interaction` can both do different things, so this can easily lead to an error.